# c# - Filename is garbled

Tags: c#, enumerate

I have a c# program that reads through directories and copies selected files.  It works fine 99.9 pct of the time, but occasionally the filename is garbled (and as far as I can tell, the length return is incorrect).

If I rerun, the file is usually found correctly

The file is on a network drive, so I suspect that the network is part of the problem.  Can anyone think of a reason for this, or at least a way of detecting a problem before trying to copy the file?  I'm finding the files with a Directory.Enumerate command, and the directory is found without any problem.

An example of the filename is  }`{~{}{}�{`~�`_�����}��_�`�}*�`~_�{}`*��}�}{�}}���.���, whereas it.s a .zip file with usual English characters.

Thanks for any advice.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var txtFiles2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_subDir); 
LoggerHelper.Debug(logger, "Dir {0}", _subDir); 
foreach (string f2 in txtFiles2) 
{ 
  LoggerHelper.Debug(logger, "DB1: FileName {0}", f2); 
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(f2); 
  LoggerHelper.Debug(logger, " File {0}", fi.Name); 
}
```

Comment: Post your code that “reads through directories and copies selected files”.

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner installed? It might be creating hidden temporary files. Otherwise I might suspect a corrupt file somewhere in the filesystem. Is the bogus filename the same every time? Is it in the same location? N.b. `string.Length` will never be wrong. If it contains non-ASCII (Unicode) characters, any length issues could be the result of improper character encoding translation with some API.

Comment: Haven't seen that specifically, but I have had intermittent issues reading and writing zip files if they are stored in a compressed network folder.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I have added a code snippet above (in the original question).

Comment: Your code sample works perfectly for me, It must be something else on your system doing it, or something in your Logger.

Comment: Maybe you want to provide a try/catch and test, It may somehow provide more info.

Comment: EnumerateFiles returns a lazily loaded IEnumerable. Is it possible that the contents of the directory is changing over the lifetime of the IEnumerable, and that is somehow causing the problem? Try using GetFiles and see if it still occurs.